# Mysqli Make connection in one function and use it for sql queries in other function

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli, database-abstraction

I was trying to make a database class similar to what most cms have, so I am making a connection in one function and returning connection object to be used for queries in other functions in class ..

```
<?php


class my_database {

    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $user = 'prince';
    var $pass = 'abcd1234wxyz';
    var $db = 'world';

    function __construct() {

        $this->db_connect();

    }

    function db_connect() {

        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

        /* check connection */
        if (!$mysqli) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        return $mysqli;
    }

    function query($query) {
        $mysqli = $this->db_connect();


        if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($row);
                echo "</pre>";
            }


            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }  else
            echo "fails"; exit;

    }


}
$database  = new my_database;

/*************** Class Ends ****************************/

function get_results() {

    global $database;
    $database->query("select * from city limit 10");

}
get_results();
?>
```

It always output `fails`, I Am new to  Oops & mysqli maybe I am missing something obvious.
Please help !

Comment: You should read a tutorial on OOP PHP, as you are making basic mistakes which are covered by every tut out there.

Comment: and whats the mistake ?

Comment: Properties, unlike variables, do not get called by simply using their name, you have to use the object operator. So if you want to access a property that's a member of the object you are currently in, you would do `$this->property_name`. Also, you're using obsolete visibility properties (`var` is PHP4, and while it's still supported for backward compatibility, you should use `public`, `protected` or `private` keywords). Globals are also very naughty, you should read up on dependency injection.

Comment: you shouldn't connect every time you want to make a query. Like Lajos Veres stated, you should put mysql resource as a property and this way you won't need to reconnect every time

Comment: can i get code of how to do it in proper way ?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

- You should access the instance variables as $this->varname. (for example in the connect you should use $this->host...)
- You should access $mysqli as an instance variable $this->mysqli.

(Otherwise there are lots of free db layer for php. for example adodb.)

Comment: can i get my code corrected ? so that i know what were my mistakes and how to do it in proper way ?

Comment: The db_mysql.inc file in the phplib package is really similar. http://sourceforge.net/projects/phplib/files/latest/download I can be a good starting point.

Comment: thankyou a ton for that ..didnt know something like this exit

Answer (score 1):

Your class is in many ways a bad practice.
First of all, you are using the old PHP4 syntax here, which is already unsupported. It is highly recommended to switch over to PHP5 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Secondly, I would use PDO rather than MySQLi. However, whichever of these you use, they already have an object orientated interface. So why using the procedural? -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php (MySQLi)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php (PDO)

Regarding your implementation, there are also some really bad practices.Just have a closer look on your db_connect() function: This is called whenever you use the query() method, meaning, you creconnect each time you do a query! This is useless, you only need one connect per request!
The solution to this is an object property which holds the open database-connection.

On top of that, in your code at the bottom you break some key concepts of OOP when using "global". Go ahead and use Dependency Injection instead, meaning to literally inject the $database object to your function ( function(my_database $db) {} ).

There are tons of implementations of what you're doing on the internet, just use google ;)

Comment: so we should not try of our own because google have trillions of result already ?

Comment: Sorry, no wasn# measnt like this, just to have a look on 'good' implementations to learn from them :)

Comment: also can you correct my code so that i can know of how to do it in proper oops way ?thankyou

Comment: See other answer for why your code isn't working properly. (Btw I also recommend to go for some basic OOP tutorials first!) Here is my result of a quick github search: https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php It also includes a basic query builder (which isnt nice normally, cause database-handle and query-builder have different concerns, so they should be two classes)